# Enum Array throwing ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, enums, instantiation

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

enum Pebble
{
    X,O,EMPTY;
}

public class Board 
{
private int count;


private Pebble[][] array;

public Board(int n)
{
    array = new Pebble[n][n];
    Arrays.fill(array, Pebble.EMPTY);     
}...
```

When I create an object of n x n elements it throws an ArrayStoreException. My array is filled with Enum constants therefore it should be a the Enum type. What is the problem?

When I instantiate the object I get these errors:

```
 Board b = new Board(6);

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: board.Pebble
 at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:3130)
 at board.Board.<init>(Board.java:28)
 at board.Tester.main(Tester.java:18)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.fill` expects to fill your `array` with `Pebble[]` instances, not `Pebble` instances.

You can fill each row of the array separately with :

```
Arrays.fill(array[i], Pebble.EMPTY);
```

So, to fill the entire 2D array, use a loop :

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    Arrays.fill(array[i], Pebble.EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the *wrong type* of object into an array of objects.

You're trying to fill the array with `Pebble.EMPTY`, which is of type `Pebble`. But the expected type is `Pebble[]`.

You can do something like:

```
for (Pebble[] pbl: array)
    Arrays.fill(pbl, Pebble.EMPTY);
```

I highly recommend checking the docs when getting a Java exception, they're usually very detailed and explained.

Comment: I did check the docs. I overlooked the fact that i had a two dimension array instead of a one-dimensional array. Which I am more familiar with using the Arrays.fill(). Thank you!

Comment: @FutureUIUXDeveloper you're welcome :) Also consider to use the debugger and check the types, it could be really helpful.